# Should an apostrophe be used in this context?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Should an apostrophe be used in the word "individual's" in the sentence  "... may disagree with some individual's worldview"?

I'm unsure if the word "individual" is possessive in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided this fragment:

> may disagre[e] with some individual's worldview

It seems that you are talking about more than one individual, so we need the plural *individuals* here. The worldview is that belonging to (possessed by) the individuals, so we need the possessive of that plural, which is *individuals'* with an S followed by an apostrophe.

If multiple individuals have the same worldview, you can talk about *some individuals' worldview*, but if each individual has his/her/their own worldview, then you would talk about *some individuals' worldviews*.